# How to apply DISTINCT selector in MySQL for just one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like the following:-

```
Table: deals
+----+-------+----------+----------+------------+
| ID |  name | latitude | longitude|  end_date  |
|----+-------+----------+----------+------------+
|  1 | pizza |    10.5  |   -10.5  | 2012-12-12 |
|  2 | pizza |    11.5  |   -10.5  | 2012-12-12 |
|  3 | jelly |    21.5  |   -10.5  | 2012-12-12 |
|  4 | jelly |    23.5  |   -10.5  | 2012-12-12 |
|  5 | lily  |    19.5  |   -10.5  | 2012-12-12 |
+----+-------+----------+----------+------------+
```

I'm using the `latitude` and `longitude` to find the distance to that person. But I need result to be `DISTINCT` based on `name`. I also need to sort the results by the distance I calculated and apply the limit 0,3.

The query I'm currently using is"-

```
SELECT *,
   ( 6371 * Acos(Cos(Radians(9.939625)) * Cos(Radians(lat)) * Cos(
                               Radians(lng) - Radians(76.259498)) +
                          Sin(Radians(9.939625)) * Sin(Radians(lat))) ) AS
   distance
FROM   deals
WHERE  1
   AND end_date >= Now()
HAVING distance < 20000
ORDER  BY id DESC,
      distance
LIMIT  0, 3;
```

So in short, what I need is:-

1. List of the closest deals (sorted by distance)
2. Apply distinct to `name` (so that both pizza and jelly will appear only once)

Comment: among the 2 distances available, you need the name with the shortest distance. is that right?

Comment: yes, correct. Need to show the closest one first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to apply `MIN` to get the minimum distance per name, `GROUP BY` name (which gives one result per name) and `ORDER BY` distance first and id later;

```
SELECT *,
   MIN( 6371 * Acos(Cos(Radians(9.939625)) * Cos(Radians(latitude)) * Cos(
                               Radians(longitude) - Radians(76.259498)) +
                          Sin(Radians(9.939625)) * Sin(Radians(latitude))) ) 
AS distance
FROM   deals
WHERE  end_date >= Now()
GROUP BY name
ORDER  BY distance, id DESC
```

I should add that this query may be ok for your case but isn't generally very useful, since if you want to know for example the latitude and longitude of the closest pizza place, you'll need an entirely different query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, 
   ( 6371 * Acos(Cos(Radians(9.939625)) * Cos(Radians(lat)) * Cos( 
                               Radians(lng) - Radians(76.259498)) + 
                          Sin(Radians(9.939625)) * Sin(Radians(lat))) ) AS 
   distance 
FROM   deals 
WHERE  1 
   AND end_date >= Now() 
GROUP BY name
HAVING distance < 20000 
ORDER  BY id DESC, 
      distance
```